# Hash table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashtable

I have the following hash table:

```
  COUNTRIES = {
  'France' => 'FR', 
  'German' => 'GE', 
  'United Kingdom' => 'UK'
  }
```

I have it in my model and use it in my views so the countries are displayed as a select box. Now I have one view where I want all those values plus one more value "Europe" => 'EU' to be shown.
Meaning I would have:

```
  COUNTRIES = {
  'Europe' => 'EU', 
  'France' => 'FR', 
  'German' => 'GE', 
  'United Kingdom' => 'UK'
  }
```

Now I can create a new hash table but I dont want to repeat the same values in a new table.

So, how can I re-use the same table, adding one more value just for a particular view?

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: Europe isn't a country!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
customCountries = COUNTRIES.clone
customCountries['Europe'] = 'EU'
```

Comment: As far as I know it's Hash.new(default_value) and that is most probably not what you wanted.

Comment: Smoother one-liner below by Jonas Elfström

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
custom = {'Europe' => 'EU'}.merge(COUNTRIES)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Europe".to_country!
```